# Stacking Lists for more targeted marketing

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I was wondering if anyone knows how to stack lists from multiple sheets into one sheet?

Example: Lets say I have a Google sheet with 3 tabs (Vacant Home, Pre-foreclosure, Probate) these tabs have property address and home owner names. I want to create another tab that will look at all three of those tabs and show me any property that is on multiple lists. so for example

- John Doe is at 123 Main street is on the Vacant tab and the Probate tab, or
- John Doe is at 123 Main street is on Vacant, Pre-Foreclosure, and Probate

This would help create more targeted marketing as people that appear on multiple lists would likely have a higher pain point and need to sell their home.

I assume its either some sort of Vlookup formula or count forumula but not sure. Any help is appreciated

tired using Vlookup but its not exactly what im looking for